# Is there a way to detect / guess the language of the page loaded by puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

Is there any built-in way, heuristics, or existing libraries / helpers for determining the language of a page loaded by puppeteer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google chrome uses multiple ways to detect the language of the page. But the most common and easiest way is to read the HTML file itself.

For example, [Japanese Quora](https://jp.quora.com) has this at beginning of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=ja>
```

Which you can simply read with an evaluate like below.

```
document.querySelector('html').lang
```

You can collect other methods to read the meta tags, and even `navigator` itself.

```
window.navigator.language
```

[acceptedlanguages.js](https://github.com/leighmcculloch/acceptedlanguages.js) is a nice library to get everything together.

Comment: Thank you, great advice. Although, `window.navigator.language` seems to be the UI language of the browser itself, not the language detected for the page it's currently displaying?

Comment: Sometimes the pages rather translate to the browsers language. It's all depends on how various websites takes care of things.